# Precompiling assets failing when trying to deploy to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to deploy my app to heroku with the terminal command `git push heroku master`, but it fails during assets precompiling and I can't make much sense of the error message.

I get the error:

```
    remote:        I, [2019-09-07T14:40:57.856531 #1633]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_1e97b201914388013420d438aaf972eb/public/assets/application-6e5c569b523cb8b97f659b2b254c3a9c22a7cbd1d9c4f17afaf18019084c6544.js.gz
    remote:        rake aborted!
    remote:        SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...e* bootstrap.*/": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "*/"
    remote:                on line 14:76 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
    remote:        >> t be set or imported *before* bootstrap.*/
    remote:        
    remote:           ------------------------------------------^
```

In application.sccs, there used to be the line:

```
    /* Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap. */
    @import "bootstrap";
    @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

But I have removed the first line and now starting on line 14 I only have:

```
    @import "bootstrap";
    @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

But the problem persists.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a semicolon

Comment: Damn, such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkMerritt, I never marked your answer as correct, I am new to SO but from what I understood you can't accept comments as the correct answer. If you'd like, post it as an answer and I will gladly accept it as the correct one.

Comment: done! Thanks for coming back and letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistakes can be the most difficult to track down...

You are just missing a semicolon...

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";  # <= that one
```

Also note that the line you removed is a css comment (which are between `/*  */`)